# google map url - how do I pass in a custom name along with lat and long in url to google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

I have the following code in a js function that is run in an onClick event:

`window.open("https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=40.669832,-73.962284&amp;ll=");`

My problem is that when the map opens up the desccriptive text next to the marker defined by the lat and long provided is incorrect.

I need to adjust this description/name of the marker that I see on the map. How do I do that? I've looked on google developer guide for parameters that I could use but don't see anything like 'name' or 'description'.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.